# jQuery to iterate over every childNodes of body

Tags: javascript, jquery

Goal: I want to iterate and print out every childNodes of the html body, and I used document.body.childNodes method. So far it's not printing out every child nodes of the body. Here's my code

```
<body>
    <p><div class="zero"><div class="one"><span class="two">hello</span></div></div></p>
</body>
```

And here's my jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log(document.body.childNodes);
});
```

My result is: 
[text, p, div.zero, p, text, item: function]

Where does the div class="one", span class="two" go? What can I do to iterate over all the childNodes of the body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you see only first level childs.

To iterate over all you can use jquery!

```
$("body").find("*").each(function(){
  var currentElement = $(this); //jquery object
  var currentElementNotJquery = this; //html element
  //some code here
});
```

Or by writing recursive procedure:

Something like that:

```
function iterate(node){
  if(node.firstChild)
    for(var i in node.childNodes)
      iterate(node.childNodes[i]);
  console.log(node);
}
```

And run them: **iterate(document.body)**

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the jquery function each:
[.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)